# A network-related or instance-specific error while trying to connect to SQL Azure from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I get the following error when I am trying to connect to SQL Azure account from My SQLServer Management studio. I use "SQL Server 2008 R2" on Windows 7 32-bit machine.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider Named
>   Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have followed the instructions from [blog.sqlauthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) but it did not help.

This is how am trying to connect to my Azure:

[image: This is how am trying to access:]

And I have noticed one more error in SQL Server Services, But all the services are running.

> The remote procedure call failed. [0x800706be]

[image]

PS: I have also added my IP address in the "Manage IP Addresses" in windows azure.

Any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very generalized question. There can have many reasons due to which you are getting this network related error.
Have you ever got it work before? Are you sure server name is correct? Can you cross check?

Or else you can check the internet connectivity and working of VPN(if you use it)

Comment: This is the first time am trying to connect to SQLAzure. Yes the server name is correct and VPN & Internet are wrking fine ...

Comment: Hmm.. looks like the 1433 port is being blocked by my company's firewall... I am marking urs as answer as it was almost near :)

Comment: got the same problem .. found out my ISP is blocking port 1433 as well .. thanks.